# Django + Javascript + "onmouseover"

Tags: javascript, django, image, onmouseover

This will be sort of general question about django + javascript. For example, I have 5 news, for each there is title, text and image. On web page all of 5 images are visible, but only 1 text and 1 title (for newest news).

Now I want to this: when mouse cursor is put over any of news' image, it title and text will by shown instead of title and text of the newest news. How to do that? I am not looking for complete solution (it would be too beautiful :), but some tips where to look.

I assume that Javascript is required (and web was written in django) but what alse? Anyone can give me some advice, how to  links etc? I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you generate the other 4 news items in a `div` or some other element, you can apply a class style to it `display: none` which will hide that piece of content. Then you can use some jQuery (or plain old javascript if you like) to show that content on mouse over.

Something like this:

```
$('img').mouseover(function(){
    var item_num = $(this).data('news-item');
    $('hidden' + item_num).show();
});
```

That assumes you have HTML something like:

```
<img src='' data-news-item='2'>
<div class='hidden2'> 
    <span id='title2'> Hi There </span> 
    <span id='text2'> ..article.. </span>
</div>
```

This is a very very basic approach and it can be done much better. But that should get you the jump you need.